# jQuery value in H3 Tag replace by value from Text Box

Tags: jquery, text, replace

i have a h3 tag

```
<h3> <a href="#"> Initial Text</a></h3>
```

and i have a TextBox.
When a Some values is typed in that TextBox

```
<input id="Medication" name="Medication" size="50" type="text" value="">
```

The value in that anchor link (Initial Text)

Should be replaced with the Value in the TextBox.

How can i do that?
can any one help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#medication').blur(function(){
  var objVal = $(this).val();
  if(objVal != ''){
    $('h3 a').text(objVal);
  }
});
```

This will attach the [blur()](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event handler to execute the provided function when the text box loses focus.  The function will check if the value is set and if it is then it will update the text in your `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 3):

Well it depends on when you want the text in the anchor to change, but it's going to involve binding an event handler to the `input` element. If you want the `a` text to change whenever a key is pressed, you could bind to the [`keypress`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) or [`keyup`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event:

```
$("#medication").keyup(function() {
    $("h3 a").text($(this).val());
});
```

If you want the text to change when the user leaves the `input` (in other words, on the `blur` event), you can bind to the [`blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event:

```
$("#medication").blur(function() {
    $("h3 a").text($(this).val());
});
```

You may want the text to change when the `input` is blurred, but only if the value has changed. If that's the case, bind to the [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event.

You may *even* want to bind a handler to more than one of these events, in which case you could use `bind`, which takes a string representing multiple events:

```
$("#medication").bind("keyup blur change", function() {
    $("h3 a").text($(this).val());
});
```

The important parts of the above code are the `$(this).val()` which will get the value entered into the `input` by the user, and the `$("h3 a").text(...)` which is what actually changes the text of the anchor.

Comment: Thank you for valuable Information for me all the three answers  worked. I am sorry i have to only select one answer as useful

Comment: What if i have multiple h3 text h3 text h3 text and i want to immediate h3 should change the value based on the immediate next text box?

Comment: Then this will change the text in all of them! You probably want to give the one you're trying to change some identifier (like an `id`) so you can target it more specifically.

Comment: okay, i will try to make those unique ids so that it wont conflict.

Comment: `id` values have to be unique in a document. Having more than one of the same `id` will cause all sorts of problems!

Answer (score 1):

OK, first you bind to the blur event of the input, then, get the value of the text input and replace the link text with that value:

```
$('#Medication').bind('blur', function(){
     var val = $(this).val(); // get value of input
     $('h3 a').html(val); // replace text of link
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first place an ID on the `<a>` tag or the `<h3>` tag. This will allow for quick reference to the anchor you are trying to modify and will make the code more efficient.

```
<h3> <a id="myAnchor" href="#"> Initial Text</a></h3>
```

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#Medication').change(function () {
    $('#myAnchor').text($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Note the above makes use of the [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/).